# импорт less файла в javascript файле

Tags: javascript, reactjs, less

решил посмотреть одну библиотеку на react. это пример использования данной библиотеки:
https://github.com/react-component/tooltip/blob/master/examples/simple.js

меня смутила эта строчка:

```
import 'rc-tooltip/assets/bootstrap.less';
```

я понимаю импорт js файла для использования, но импорт less файла.. это как?? можете помочь дать ссылку или рассказать как компилировать\собирать такие файлы? вообще я использую для сборки gulp, babel. а файлы less я собираю отдельно..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте webpack (https://webpack.github.io/) Потом можно подключить less-loader и другое. А для выноса стилей в отдельный файл используют extract-text-plugin.

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: "style!css!less"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: можно еще вопросик? я немного полазил в нете и правильно ли я понял, что такой прием умеет обрабатывать только webpack?

Comment: Похоже что да, других решений не встречал, так как с react я всегда использовал webpack. А в обычных проектах на PHP, например,  Gulp.

Но во в всяком случае, Gulp - это менеджер тасков, а webpack - сборщик всего, поэтому их можно использовать совместно.